# Merge the list of dictionary if there are some condition is match?

Tags: python

```
input = [
{'date':'2023-03-1', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 11, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},
{'date':'2023-03-2', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 12, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},
{'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 13, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},

{'date':'2023-04-2', 'item':'i2', 'balance': 11, 'warehouse' : 'W2'},
{'date':'2023-04-3', 'item':'i2', 'balance': 10, 'warehouse' : 'W2'},

{'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 10, 'warehouse' : 'W3'},
]
```

If Lookup: `item='i1' and  date ='2023-03-3'`

I want the put like this:

`[{'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1' , 'W1':13,'W2':0: W2:10}]`

The goal is to display this in format:

```
   Date   | item | W1 | W2 | W3
2023-03-3 | i1   | 13 | 0  | 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy approach is to load the data into a Pandas DataFrame and then, if really needed, to convert it back to a dictionary:

```
input = [
    {"date": "2023-03-1", "item": "i1", "balance": 11, "warehouse": "W1"},
    {"date": "2023-03-2", "item": "i1", "balance": 12, "warehouse": "W1"},
    {"date": "2023-03-3", "item": "i1", "balance": 13, "warehouse": "W1"},
    {"date": "2023-04-2", "item": "i2", "balance": 11, "warehouse": "W2"},
    {"date": "2023-04-3", "item": "i2", "balance": 10, "warehouse": "W2"},
    {"date": "2023-03-3", "item": "i1", "balance": 10, "warehouse": "W3"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(input)

df_grouped = df.groupby(["date", "item", "warehouse"]).sum().reset_index()
df_pivot = df_grouped.pivot(
    index=["date", "item"], columns="warehouse", values="balance"
)
```

The resulting DataFrame is this:

```
warehouse         W1    W2    W3
date      item
2023-03-1 i1    11.0   NaN   NaN
2023-03-2 i1    12.0   NaN   NaN
2023-03-3 i1    13.0   NaN  10.0
2023-04-2 i2     NaN  11.0   NaN
2023-04-3 i2     NaN  10.0   NaN
```

Then, to convert to a dictionary:

```
output = df_pivot.reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[
 {'date': '2023-03-1', 'item': 'i1', 'W1': 11.0, 'W2': nan, 'W3': nan}, 
 {'date': '2023-03-2', 'item': 'i1', 'W1': 12.0, 'W2': nan, 'W3': nan}, 
 {'date': '2023-03-3', 'item': 'i1', 'W1': 13.0, 'W2': nan, 'W3': 10.0}, 
 {'date': '2023-04-2', 'item': 'i2', 'W1': nan, 'W2': 11.0, 'W3': nan}, 
 {'date': '2023-04-3', 'item': 'i2', 'W1': nan, 'W2': 10.0, 'W3': nan}
]
```

I suggest, however, to keep it in DataFrame format, since it's way easier to manipulate data then using a simple dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the pandas library, you can use a pivot table to get what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(inputs)
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'item'], columns='warehouse', fill_value=0).reset_index(level=(0,1), col_level=1)
pivot
pivot.columns = pivot.columns.droplevel(0)
pivot.to_dict('records')
# returns:
[{'date':'2023-03-1', 'item':'i1', 'W1': 11, 'W2':0, 'W3': 0},
 {'date':'2023-03-2', 'item':'i1', 'W1': 12, 'W2':0, 'W3': 0},
 {'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1', 'W1': 13, 'W2':0, 'W3': 10},
 {'date':'2023-04-2', 'item':'i2', 'W1': 0, 'W2':11, 'W3': 0},
 {'date':'2023-04-3', 'item':'i2', 'W1': 0, 'W2':10, 'W3': 0}]
```

If you don't want to use pandas, you can pivot the data with a script:

```
pivot = {}
warehouses = set()
for d in inputs:
    k1 = d['date']
    k2 = d['item']
    w = d['warehouse']
    c = d['balance']
    warehouses.add(w)
    counts = pivot.setdefault((k1, k2), {})
    counts[w] = c
records = [{'date': k1, 'item': k2
```

Then to show it:

```
for (k1, k2) in sorted(pivot):
    counts = pivot[(k1, k2)]
    ws = ' | '.join(str(counts.get(w, 0)) for w in sorted(warehouses))
    print(f'{k1} | {k2} | {ws}')

# prints:
2023-03-1 | i1 | 11 | 0 | 0
2023-03-2 | i1 | 12 | 0 | 0
2023-03-3 | i1 | 13 | 0 | 10
2023-04-2 | i2 | 0 | 11 | 0
2023-04-3 | i2 | 0 | 10 | 0
```

Comment: I need the result sent to the defined html template, but Can I transform the result of `df.pivot_table` into a list of dictionaries?

Comment: ok, that is additional info we needed.  yes.

Comment: `df.to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 1):

There are some fine answers here, but if you want an answer that does not involve pandas or one that does not require hard coding the filters, I think you can try something like this.

The strategy here is to use `setdefault()` to build up a keyed dictionary of values that you will ultimately convert to a list.

```py
data = [
    {'date':'2023-03-1', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 11, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},
    {'date':'2023-03-2', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 12, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},
    {'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 13, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},
    {'date':'2023-04-2', 'item':'i2', 'balance': 11, 'warehouse' : 'W2'},
    {'date':'2023-04-3', 'item':'i2', 'balance': 10, 'warehouse' : 'W2'},
    {'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 10, 'warehouse' : 'W3'},
]

data2 = {}
for row in data:
    key = f"{ row['date'] }_{ row['item'] }"
    data2.setdefault(
        key,
        {"date": row["date"], "item": row["item"], "W1": 0, "W2": 0, "W3": 0}
    )[row["warehouse"]] = row["balance"]
data2 = list(data2.values())

import json
print(json.dumps(data2))
```

That will give you:

```
[
    {"date": "2023-03-1", "item": "i1", "W1": 11, "W2": 0, "W3": 0},
    {"date": "2023-03-2", "item": "i1", "W1": 12, "W2": 0, "W3": 0},
    {"date": "2023-03-3", "item": "i1", "W1": 13, "W2": 0, "W3": 10},
    {"date": "2023-04-2", "item": "i2", "W1": 0, "W2": 11, "W3": 0},
    {"date": "2023-04-3", "item": "i2", "W1": 0, "W2": 10, "W3": 0}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
input = [
{'date':'2023-03-1', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 11, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},
{'date':'2023-03-2', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 12, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},
{'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 13, 'warehouse' : 'W1'},

{'date':'2023-04-2', 'item':'i2', 'balance': 11, 'warehouse' : 'W2'},
{'date':'2023-04-3', 'item':'i2', 'balance': 10, 'warehouse' : 'W2'},

{'date':'2023-03-3', 'item':'i1', 'balance': 10, 'warehouse' : 'W3'},
]

new_list = []
for i in input:
    if(i['item']=="i1" and i['date']=='2023-03-3'):
        
        val = {
            'item':"i1",
            'date':"2023-03-3",
            i['warehouse']:i['balance']
        }
        new_list.append(val)
        
print(new_list)
```

EDITED.

Comment: it is it's balance value

Answer (score 0):

you can try below

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(input).groupby(['date', 'item', 'warehouse'])['balance'].apply(int).unstack().reset_index()
    
    
    #prints
    print(df)
    
    warehouse       date item    W1    W2    W3
    0          2023-03-1   i1  11.0   NaN   NaN
    1          2023-03-2   i1  12.0   NaN   NaN
    2          2023-03-3   i1  13.0   NaN  10.0
    3          2023-04-2   i2   NaN  11.0   NaN
    4          2023-04-3   i2   NaN  10.0   NaN
```